# How to insert the current_timestamp for newly inserted rows

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need to insert the data with timestamp daily three times. I need to insert current_timestamp in null values in the time column

```
update tablename 
  set time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE time = null
```

```
 name   | marks |            time
 ---------+-------+----------------------------
 GANESH  |    80 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 GANESH  |    90 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 GANESH  |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 SURESH  |    10 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 SURESH  |    20 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 SURESH  |    30 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 RAKESH  |    90 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 Vishnu  |   900 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 VITAL   |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 SEENU   |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
 VITAL1  |   100 |
 VITAL12 |   100 |
 VITAL13 |   100 |
 raj     |       |
 raj1    |       |
 raj2    |       |
```

I am expecting to insert the current_timestamp in null places

```
  name   | marks |            time
    ---------+-------+----------------------------
     GANESH  |    80 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     GANESH  |    90 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     GANESH  |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     SURESH  |    10 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     SURESH  |    20 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     SURESH  |    30 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     RAKESH  |    90 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     Vishnu  |   900 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     VITAL   |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     SEENU   |   100 | 2019-01-06 05:03:24.171124
     VITAL1  |   100 | 2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
     VITAL12 |   100 | 2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
     VITAL13 |   100 | 2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
     raj     |       | 2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
     raj1    |       | 2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
     raj2    |       |2019-01-07 11:03:24.171124
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a column against `NULL`, you need to use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` operators.  So, the following should work:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE time IS NULL;
```

This question is almost a typo question, except that understanding what `NULL` semantically means in SQL is more than a typo issue.  The `NULL` value itself means "not known," so it makes no sense to use `=` to check it.